# HTML5 Video JQUERY causing compounded uncaught promise exceptions

Tags: jquery, html, video

Outside of the console full of promise exceptions in the chrome developer tools this is working as expected. However, from what little I understand, I would expect this to crash the browser eventually.

Here are the errors in the log:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to load().

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.vidarray').get(0).pause();
$('.video').hide();
$('#div1').show();
$('#video1').get(0).load();
$('#video1').get(0).play();
$('#video1').on('ended', addVideo2);
});

var addVideo2 = function() {
$('.vidarray').get(0).pause();
$('.video').hide();
$('#div2').show();
$('#video2').get(0).load();
$('#video2').get(0).play();
$('#video2').on('ended', addVideo3);
};

var addVideo3 = function() {
$('.vidarray').get(0).pause();
$('.video').hide();
$('#div3').show();
$('#video3').get(0).load();
$('#video3').get(0).play();
$('#video3').on('ended', addVideo1);
};

var addVideo1 = function() {
$('.vidarray').get(0).pause();
($('.video').hide());
$('#div1').show();
$('#video1').get(0).load();
$('#video1').get(0).play();
$('#video1').on('ended', addVideo3);
};
```

And the HTML if needed:

```
<div id="div1" class="video"><video id="video1" class="vidarray" preload="none" poster="bkg.png"><source src="icx.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<div id="div2" class="video"><video id="video2" class="vidarray" preload="none" poster="bkg.png"><source src="icx2.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<div id="div3" class="video"><video id="video3" class="vidarray" preload="none" poster="bkg.png"><source src="lastvid.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what was the question?

Comment: Why would you expect this to crash the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because each of your `addVideoX` functions adds a new event handler on its video each time it is run.

Moreover your `$('.vidarray').get(0).pause();` always stops the first video only.

Since your code is identical i would create a method that identifies the next video (*with a class*) and performs the load/start/pause

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var videos = $('.video');
  
  //handle ending of video
  videos.find('video').on('ended', function(){
    playNextVideo(videos);
  });
  
  // start with the first one
  playNextVideo(videos);
});
  
function playNextVideo(videoList){
  var activeVideo = videoList.filter('.active').removeClass('active'), // identify active video and remove active class
      activeIndex = videoList.index(activeVideo), // get the active video index in the group
      nextVideo = videoList.eq(activeIndex+1), // get the next video in line
      actualVideo;

  // if there is no next video start from first
  if (nextVideo.length == 0) nextVideo = videoList.first(); 
  
  // pause all videos
  videoList.find('video').each(function(){this.pause();}) 
  
  // get reference to next video element
  actualVideo = nextVideo.find('video').get(0);
  
  // add active class to next video
  nextVideo.addClass('active');
  
  // load and play
  actualVideo.load();
  actualVideo.play();
}
```

```css
.video{display:none}
.video.active{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1" class="video">1:<video id="video1" class="vidarray" preload="none" poster="http://dummyimage.com/320x240"><source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<div id="div2" class="video">2:<video id="video2" class="vidarray" preload="none" poster="http://dummyimage.com/320x240"><source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<div id="div3" class="video">3:<video id="video3" class="vidarray" preload="none" poster="http://dummyimage.com/320x240"><source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
```